# Does this v-html have xss issues

Tags: javascript, vue.js, xss

I'm trying to work with v-html without xss issues. I think I am using v-html in a safe way. Could you take a look to validate that I am avoiding xss issues?

Users would input a text field ("words"). This would be stored in a database. When the content is pulled from the database, the javascript would render words between two tags "/b/" as bolded words.

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/kiggs1881/pen/KKxEJbx

Here is the code:

```
const VueApp = defineComponent({

setup() {
    const words = ref("Hello /b/World/b/, I am a 
    /b/friend/b/.")
    
    const parseWords = (text) => {
        return text
    .split("/b/")
    .map((part, i) => {
      return i % 2 ? `<strong>${part}</strong>` : part;
    })
    .join(" ");
    }
    
    return {
        parseWords,
        words
    
    }
  },
   template: `
  <input v-model="words">
  <div v-html="parseWords(words)"></div>`
  })
```

I understand that v-html is vulnerable to xss attacks, but I'm hoping that the limited way I propose to use it eliminates the possibility of attacks.

Comment: This is not "limited" use, this is regular use that allows a culprit to render arbitrary html in other users' browsers. Just don't do this. You don't need v-html for this kind of usage

Comment: Same as the other poster mentions, you don't need v-html, just use `<div>{{ parsedWords }}</div>`. See https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/vue-xss-guide-examples-and-prevention/#exploring-the-vulnerability

Comment: Good resource, @mikemaccana. I used the v-html because it appeared to be the most efficient way to render the bolded language (just using it in the div without more logic doesn't work) if there are many entries of "words" that will be parsed. I haven't figured out non-v-html use yet

Comment: @mikemaccana the text interpolation will end up rendering the `<strong>` tags as plain text instead of html.  @EstusFlask how would you render the given `words` string, with the requirement that certain substrings be replaced with html tags, without v-html?  I think v-html is necessary here, but with sanitization of course.

Comment: @yoduh I imagine Vue has some looping mechanism inbuilt into its templating language. I'd use that to loop over `parsedWords` and render `<strong>{{ parsedWord }}</strong>`.

Comment: @jdost_26 I added an answer, Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per looking into your code, I would say Yes. It's vulnerable to `XSS` attack.

As you are taking an input from user. So in that case user can enter any malicious tags or script through he input box and while rendering/saving that data will attack on your application.

**Solution :** You should sanitize the user input after receiving and before submitting that to database. To achieve this you can remove the blacklist characters from the string.

Just for a better understanding, I am adding a working demo in Vanilla JavaScript (You can make it work as per Vue), Also, you can add more invalid characters in the blacklist regex.

```js
const blackListRegex = /(<[^>]+>|<[^>]>|<\/[^>]+>)/ig

function sanitizeInput() {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById('words').value;
  console.log(inputValue.replace(blackListRegex, '')); // This will be the final string which you can store in the database and render in the HTML template.
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="words" id="words" onBlur="sanitizeInput()"/>
```

Comment: You should never sanitize on the client side. It can easily be circumvented by any malicious actor.

Comment: @posixpascal That's correct. I just gave an idea. PO can do the same at backend as well for a safer side.